# Kill audio after deliberate or accidental exit of dialog

Tags: android, onclick

This is part of the code in my MainActivity.
stopwatch1 is an image button called in MainActivity:

```
           stopwatch1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.stopwatch1);
```

I have tried searching for clues on how to use dialog.setOnDismissListener, however, there aren't proper answers to help me with the killing of the audio after deliberate or accidental exit of the dialog. Any help would be appreciated.

```
           stopwatch1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        final Dialog mmDialog1 = new Dialog(context);
                        mmDialog1.setContentView(R.layout.countdowntimer);
                        mmDialog1.setTitle("Stop-watch");            
                        Button ddButton1 = (Button) mmDialog1.findViewById(R.id.countdown_exit);
                        final Button ddButton2 = (Button) mmDialog1.findViewById(R.id.countdown_start);
                        final TextView timeview = (TextView) mmDialog1.findViewById(R.id.timeview);
                        ddButton2.setTag(1);

                        ddButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                final int status = (Integer) v.getTag();

                                if (status == 1) {
                                    ddButton2.setText("Stop");
                                    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {

                                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                            int time = (int) (millisUntilFinished/1000);
                                            timeview.setText(Integer.toString(time));
                                        }
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFinish() {
                                            timeview.setText("60");
                                            ddButton2.setText("Start");
                                            MediaPlayer stop = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.stop);
                                            stop.start();
                                        }
                                    }.start();
                                    v.setTag(0);

                                } else {
                                    ddButton2.setText("Start");
                                    timeview.setText("60");
                                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                                    v.setTag(1);
                                }
                            }

                        });

                        ddButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                mmDialog1.dismiss();
                            }
                        });

                        mmDialog1.show();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to implement an interface. When the dialog closes, have the callback shut off the media player.

A quick example is this.

**interface**

```
public interface DialogClosed {
    void shutDownMediaPlayer();
}
```

then implement the interface in the calling activity

**activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements DialogClosed {
    ....
    @Override
    public void shutDownMediaPlayer() {
        //shut down media player here
    }
}
```

Also, you may add a boolean to check if the dialog is showing like this

```
boolean isShowing = mDialog.isShowing();
```

and then you can just shut off the media player at any point if this is false.

Answer (score 0):

So I've used some pointers from Jawascript and also edited my code a little, now it works:

```
            stopwatch1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        final Dialog mmDialog1 = new Dialog(context);
                        mmDialog1.setContentView(R.layout.countdowntimer);
                        mmDialog1.setTitle("Stop-watch");            
                        Button ddButton1 = (Button) mmDialog1.findViewById(R.id.countdown_exit);
                        final Button ddButton2 = (Button) mmDialog1.findViewById(R.id.countdown_start);
                        final TextView timeview = (TextView) mmDialog1.findViewById(R.id.timeview);
                        final MediaPlayer stop = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.stop);

                        ddButton2.setTag(1);

                        mmDialog1.setCancelable(false);

                        if (mmDialog1.isShowing() == false) {
                            stop.stop();
                        }

                        ddButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                final int status = (Integer) v.getTag();

                                if (status == 1) {
                                    ddButton2.setText("Stop");
                                    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {

                                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                            int time = (int) (millisUntilFinished/1000);
                                            timeview.setText(Integer.toString(time));
                                        }
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFinish() {
                                            timeview.setText("60");
                                            ddButton2.setText("Start");
                                            try {
                                                stop.prepare();
                                            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                            stop.start();
                                        }
                                    }.start();
                                    v.setTag(0);

                                } else {
                                    ddButton2.setText("Start");
                                    timeview.setText("60");
                                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                                    v.setTag(1);
                                    stop.stop();
                                }
                            }

                        });

                        ddButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                mmDialog1.dismiss();
                            }
                        });

                        mmDialog1.show();
                    }
                });
```